# sfdx cli - Unable to create scratch org | Error authenticating with JWT- invalid assertion

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-error

we are having some issue starting today (22 Nov) Everything was working till date. Starting today morning we are unable to create new scratch org.

sfdx CLI command we run

```
sfdx force:org:create -f config/project-scratch-def.json --setalias TestExt2 --durationdays 30 --setdefaultusername --json --loglevel fatal
```

sf CLI Command we run

```
sf org create scratch -f config/project-scratch-def.json
```

Error

```
Error authenticating with JWT.\nErrors encountered:\ninvalid assertion\ninvalid assertion\ninvalid assertion\ninvalid assertion\ninvalid assertion

Error (1): Error authenticating with JWT.
Errors encountered:
invalid assertion
invalid assertion
invalid assertion
invalid assertion
invalid assertion
```

Notes:

- Devhub is verify and linked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have uninstalled sfdx cli and installed it again. Resolved!